# Return a string on button click in React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to print a string upon button click inside React hooks.

This button called "More Info" is inside a return tag of a hook I created. (JSX) when this is clicked it calls another function component called "ChangeName" that should print a string.

I am not sure if I am writing some wrong syntax or missing something? The console.log inside the function displays the string in the log but the div tag just doesn't print the string on the console,

created a custom hook and the button is inside its return tag.

```
 <button onClick ={ChangeName}>More Info <button>
```

onclick should call and print results from the below function

```
 function ChangeName(){ 
         console.log("This is a test") //works
          return (<div>"This is a test"</div>)
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tt's not related react hook , if you want to print string above button you should make a state use `useState` from react hooks

```
const SomeComp = () => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState("")
   const changeName = () => {
      setValue("some value changed")
   }
   return (
     <>
     {value.length > 0 && <div>{value}</div>}
     <button onClick={changeName}>Change Name</button>
     </>
   )
}
```

Comment: hey i tried to add the code you shared but it still doesn't display the output

Comment: basic structure of my code  is as follows.    function Data{ some code that pulls a list from API return ( loops through to display the list within <li> tags. Each loop has a button called More Info. Onclick of this button will trigger another function called Change Name that should display the details.  SInce my button click isnt working I am trying to output a simple string to start with. Once that works will I be able to pass an Object to display its details

Comment: it"s worked, i try in blank project. do you see any error ? You should up more detail code

Comment: I am now trying to output the data when the button is clicked. (in the link shared above) instead of a simple string.

Comment: i dont see any extra data you want to show but the idea is when you click button more info, you should have a state as an array to contain your selected id of item you want to show more info .

Comment: Duy, I have updated the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hamilton-erkqv?fontsize=14       ChangeName event handler is now taking an object  called 'x'. It is letting me print the name via x.name but i also want to print its id and type.. How would i do that?

Comment: Please help as I am unable to extract  more than one key from the object 'x' passed to ChangeName.? what should i do?? i tried to convert it into an array with object.keys but when i map through it gives an error saying cannot use map function

Comment: you mean you want to add 1 more key into that data ?

Comment: Duy I was able to fix that. Thanks!